# How to count equal values in a row in a column

Tags: python, count

I would like to find with Python the way to find blocks of x equal values or more in a row in a column.

E.g. given a dataset, I would like to find blocks of three or more in a row of True in the column Value and create a new column with the result:

```
ID      Value     New column
1       True      False
2       True      False
3       False     False
4       False     False
5       False     False
6       True      True
7       True      True
8       True      True
9       False     False
10      False     False
11      True      False
12      True      False
13      False     False
14      True      True
.       True      True
.       True      True
..      True      True
```

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear. Can you explain again?

Comment: sorry I think my first explanation is not clear.

Comment: we star with a dataser with two columns, ID and Value, (True or False) and the goal is to create another column "New Column"  where to get True, there have to be at least three True values together (in a row) or more, if tdont the result is False although there is True in "Value" column.

Comment: Are you using a specific library such as `pandas`?  If so, please add that as a tag to the question.  The answers to the question may look quite different with different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem would be to use 2 loops. Note that this is quick and dirty code and not optimized for efficiency

1. First Loop - just populate data for all the 3 columns with a default value of False for the 3rd column.
2. Second Loop - Now go through each row. If the value of the 3rd column is **not already** set to True, check the value of 2nd column for that row and the next 2 rows i.e. row(i), row(i+1), row(i+2). If the values are all True then you update the value of the 3rd column to True for that row and the next 2 rows.

Example you're on row 6 where the 3rd column is False, you check the values of the 2nd column for row 6, 7, 8 and they are all True, so you update the value of the 3rd column for rows 6,7,8 to True

Since you are only checking rows where the 3rd column is False, it means you will then skip rows 7, 8 (so they don't get overwritten back to False) and you should land on row 9 where again the 3rd column is False

```
    for i in range(len(rows) ):
        try:
            if not rows[i][2]: # Ignore any row where the third column is already set to True
                if all(rows[i][1], rows[i+1][1], rows[i+2][1]):
                    rows[i][2] = True
                    rows[i+1][2] = True
                    rows[i+2][2] = True
           
        except Exception, inst:
            continue # if row(i+1) or row(i+2) doesn't exist, continue or exit the loop
```

The try except block takes care of when you get towards the end of the rows where you don't have row (i+1) or row(i+2)